# ui-router named views and ng-controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have named views:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    '' : {
      templateUrl: '/layouts/main.html',
      controller: ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.css.background = "#ebeced";
      }]
    },
    'nav@home': { templateUrl: '/templates/nav.html' },
    'menu@home': { templateUrl: '/home/menu.html'},
    'main@home': { templateUrl: '/templates/feed.html' },
    'footer@home': { templateUrl: '/home/footer.html' }
  }
})
```

and `main.html` looks like this (notice the ng-controller):

```
<div ng-controller="baseCtrl">
  <div ui-view="nav"></div>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="menu">
      <div ui-view="menu"></div>
    </div>

    <div ui-view="main"></div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div ui-view="footer"></div>  
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My `baseCtrl` is not recognising `ng-model` values in text boxes in any of the `ui-view`s.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="url" ng-blur="addUrl()" />
```

and the `baseCtrl`:

```
$scope.url = ""; //required or get error about not being defined
$scope.addUrl = function() {
  console.log($scope.url); //nothing???
}
```

Am I making a stupid mistake anywhere?

**UPDATE:**
I think I've solved the problem - I need to define `baseCtrl` as the controller for each view too.

Comment: You should write the answer and accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This block may be uncorrect:

```
'' : {
 templateUrl: '/layouts/main.html',
//..etc
```

Are you sure that unnamed item should be a key in the state config object? You may try to put it differenlty:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: '/layouts/main.html',
  controller: ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.css.background = "#ebeced";
  }],
  views: {
    'nav@home': { templateUrl: '/templates/nav.html' },
    'menu@home': { templateUrl: '/home/menu.html'},
    'main@home': { templateUrl: '/templates/feed.html' },
    'footer@home': { templateUrl: '/home/footer.html' }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have named views, `templateUrl` is overruled.